# What exactly can I return from a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an AJAX request that sends information off to a page with POST, and returns the following:

```
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo $product1;
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
            echo $code1;
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
            echo $value1;
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
            echo $time1;
        echo '</td>';


    echo '</tr>';
//  echo '</table>';

    echo 'Your code has been successfully redeemed!';
```

This is my code on the client-side:

```
        }else{

        $('#poo tr:last').after(result);

    }
```

My question is... although this works fine as this is appended on to the end of a table client side, I would also like to pass through another variable to be used in PHP, or more specifically, a database query result that can be used within PHP.

Cant seem to figure out how to output different stuff as it will mess up my current arrangement of just echoing out HTML.

Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not just return all the variables you need in JSON format?

Comment: I thought that was going to be the first answer, but ive looked everywhere for something to tell me how to do this (really basicly) and I cant find anytihng..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a json structure:

```
echo json_encode( array( "html" => $myhtml, "otherdata" => $myotherdata ) );
```

and then in jquery access each part.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myhandler.php",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(json){
  $('#foo tr:last').after(json.html);
  alert(json.otherdata);
});
```

Note, however, if `$myotherdata` is an associative array (or object as we call it in javascript) the alert will simply show `[object Object]` ( which is not an error! reference it's properties with dot syntax or array syntax `json.otherdata.key` or `json.otherdata["key"]` )

Comment: Ok thats returning "undefined". Ive looked about and it seems like I should be using JSON.parse? Or is there a reason its returning this?

Comment: Ok no scrap that, its working. Fiddled around a bit and its ok lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can return whatever you want from your AJAX request; you just need to tell JQuery how to handle it.

If you use `$.getJSON` to invoke the AJAX request, then you can encode a PHP structure using `json_encode`, and it will appear in JS with a similar structure.

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the data in JSON format and read from it. for example in PHP you could build a multi dimensional array consisting of different types of data you want. consider the below multi dimensional array.

```
$array = array(
    'table' => array(
        $product1, 
        $code1, 
        $value1,
        $time1,
    ),
    'anothervar' => array(
        'someValue',
        'anotherVal',
        'someMoreval',
        'andValue',
    ),
    'somemorevar' => array(
        'data',
        'someMoreData',
        'anotherData'
    ),
);
```

convert that into JSON using PHP's json_encode function.

```
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

and then read the data from JSON using javascript. and do whatever you like to.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I don't write PHP code regularly, but you just need to change your format from a table structure to JSON:

```
echo '{';
        echo 'Product1:';
            echo $product1;


        echo ',Code1:';
            echo $code1;


        echo ',Value1:';
            echo $value1;


        echo ',Time1:';
            echo $time1;



    echo '}';
```

And then change your client script to take this JSON object and build up your table structure on the client side.  You can then also pass other variables in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with finding JSON information. It is out there, you just must look. In the meantime, you can use the javascript `.split()` function and create some ridiculous sequence of characters. For instance.

```
<?php 

echo //EVERYTHING YOU WANT IN THE FIRST PART;
echo '|#@!|';
echo //EVERYTHING YOU WANT IN THE SECOND PART;

?>
```

and on the jQuery side

```
...function(result(){
  var resultArray = result.split('|#@!|');
  // YOU NOW HAVE BOTH PARTS. ONE IS IN resultArray[0], THE OTHER IN resultArray[1]
});
```

Hope this helps.